# What's the right way to define the <content> tag?

Tags: html, web, polymer, web-component

When defining an insertion point for light DOM in WebComponents, is there any difference between these two syntaxes?

```html
<template id="my-element">
    <content></content>
</template>
```

and

```html
<template id="my-element">
    <content/>
</template>
```

What's the **right** or the **best** way to define the  tag?

I tested both syntaxes in Firefox/Chrome and they behave identically (at least in a simple test).

Comment: **Please**, if you **down vote** my question, leave a *comment* explaining what you think is wrong with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content :

> Tag omission: None, **both the starting and ending tag are mandatory**.